# Python DTLS - Server Will Not Accept Connections

Tags: python, udp, dtls

I have been learning, through a veil of many tears, the concepts of network programming. I started with a simple UDP client/server pair, moved to TCP, and then secured the TCP stream successfully using TLS. Now I am trying to "defeat the final boss", and secure UDP communication using DTLS.

I put together a very simple UDP client/server pair using DTLS to attempt and successfully exchange encrypted communications. Let me break down the problem into the client and server.

**DTLS Client**

```
import socket
import ssl
from dtls import do_patch
do_patch()

serverAddress, serverPort = "IP Address", 12345
addr = (serverAddress, serverPort)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
SSLSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(s, '.\key.pem', '\cert.pem', server_side=False)

SSLSocket.connect(addr)
clientMessage = bytes(('I am the UDP client').encode('utf-8'))

SSLSocket.send(clientMessage)
```

`Client Hello` is successfully seen in Wireshark using the DTLS protocol.

**DTLS Server**

```
import ssl
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
from dtls import do_patch
do_patch()

##### Server and Socket Parameters #####
serverAddress, serverPort = "192.168.1.158", 12345
addr = (serverAddress, serverPort)

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, '.\key.pem', '.\cert.pem', server_side=True)
sock.bind(addr)
sock.listen(2)
clientSocket, addr = sock.accept()
print("Connection established")
```

Server program runs successfully, however the client does not seem to be able to connect. The server never acknowledges the `Client Hello`, and this is reflected by the client retransmitting its hello message at regular intervals.

I could not get a `Print()` statement in the server after `sock.listen(2)`. I'm not 100% sure what this could mean. Either the server is listening and waiting, the `Print()` statement not executing, or something else that is not causing a runtime error.

Regardless, `sock.accept()` never gets reached, and the client is stuck sending Hello messages forever. I'm not sure what the issue is, and would greatly appreciate some feedback on the matter.

Comment: You may use a known working client and server and do some cross tests. Depending on your skill, Eclipse/tinydtls (C) or Eclipse/Californium (Java) do a good job. You may also try to connect your client against the Californium sandbox, https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium#interop-server. Just to see the DTLS handshake, no need for CoAP:

Comment: Client : "IP Address", 12345 and what does Wireshark show as destination of the Client_Hello?